# Where can I find my LUIS authoring key?

Tags: azure-language-understanding, conversationlearner

[Conversation Learner](https://github.com/Microsoft/conversationLearner-samples) requires that I provide a LUIS authoring key (LUIS_AUTHORING_KEY).   How do I get one and where do I find it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Open up the [LUIS website](https://www.luis.ai)
- Login / Sign up (if you don't already have an account)
- click on your name up the upper right (on black bar)

[image]

- Then click "settings"
- That will take you to a page with your "Authoring Key"

Answer (score 0):

As Lars mentioned above you can find the keys under settings of your account. You can find more information about the Authoring key [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-keys#programmatic-key) and manage [LUIS keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/manage-keys) and [Azure endpoint subscription keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/azureibizasubscription) too. Hope this docs help you in providing more information.